# C# Cassandra Datastax driver - Handling failed connection

Tags: c#, cassandra

Is there any way to catch the connection exception thrown by the datastax cassandra driver for C#? It usually works fine, but the catch block does not execute when the remote host is down (that is, when a NoHostAvailableException is thrown). The debugger only halts and indicates the exception at Connect().

```
        try
        {
            cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint("<ip address>").Build();
            session = (Session)cluster.Connect();
        }
        catch (NoHostAvailableException ex)
        {
            //Never executes
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Never executes
        }
```

Comment: Your last edit should be an answer itself.  You can answer your own question...adding the text from your edit should be sufficient.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot about that.

Comment: No worries!  This way, it's easier for others to see the answer, and it's better for you as it should help you get more rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the fix, Visual Studio has a checkbox where you can choose whether or not you want to break on a certain exception (regardless of a try/catch), unchecking that solved everything.